# Show that a function is continuous in order to use extreme value theorem

Tags: continuity, extreme-value-theorem

Let $f:\mathcal{Z}\times\mathcal{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on a compact metric space $(\mathcal{Z},\rho)$ such that $\forall z_1,z_2\in\mathcal{Z}$
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|\le L\rho(z_1,z_2)+K\alpha
\end{equation}
where $L,K$ and $\alpha$ are constants.

I want to show that $f$ is bounded from above. Now, Extreme Value theorem can be used to show that a continuous function on a compact space is bounded.

### Can I say that $f$ is continuous because for all $z_1,z_2\in\mathcal{Z}, \epsilon>0$, whenever $\rho(z_1,z_2)<\epsilon$, $|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|<L\epsilon+K\alpha$.

or Let's look at a modified version of this question:

Let $f:\mathcal{Z}\times\mathcal{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on a compact metric space $(\mathcal{Z},\rho)$ such that $\forall z_1,z_2\in\mathcal{Z}$
\begin{equation}
|f(z_1,e_1)-f(z_2,e_2)|\le L\rho(z_1,z_2)+K\|e_1-e_2\|
\end{equation}
where $L,K$ and $\|e_1-e_2\|\leq\alpha$ are constants.

I want to show that $f$ is bounded from above. Now, Extreme Value theorem can be used to show that a continuous function on a compact space is bounded.

### Can I now say that $f$ is continuous because for all $z_1,z_2\in\mathcal{Z}, \epsilon>0$, whenever $\rho(z_1,z_2)<\epsilon$, $|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|<L\epsilon+K\alpha$.

Comment: No you can't conclude continuity. You can't make $K \alpha$ small because it is fixed.

Comment: I have included a modified version of the question. Can we now say that it is continuous and thus bounded due to EVT?

Answer (score 1):

It can be discontinuous. For example, chose a particular point $x$, and define $f(z)$ to be $K\alpha$ if $z = x$, $0$ if not. Then this is discontinuous but for all $z_1$, $z_2$, you have $|f(z_1)-f(z_2)| \leqslant K\alpha \leqslant L\rho(z_1,z_2) + K\alpha$.

What is true is that $f$ is bounded because 
for $z,t_0 \in \mathcal{Z}$
\begin{align}
|f(z)| &=|f(z)-f(t_0) + f(t_0)| \\ & \leqslant |f(z)-f(t_0)| + |f(t_0)| \\&\leqslant L \rho(z,t_0) + K\alpha + |f(t_0)| \\&\leqslant  L\mathrm{diam}\mathcal{Z} + K\alpha + |f(t_0)|
\end{align}
(recall that $\mathcal{Z}$ is compact thus as a finite diameter.)
So if $t$ is fixed, $f$ is bounded by the constant $L\mathrm{diam}\mathcal{Z} + K\alpha + |f(t_0)|$.

Comment: but what about $|f(t)|$. I mean it can still be unbounded?

Comment: If $t$ is fixed, this is a constant. Thus $f(z)$ is bounded by a constant not depending on $z$.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand it. Is $t\in\mathcal{Z}$? then how can we say that $f(t)$ can't be unbounded? Please accept my apology if it should be self evident.

Comment: As $\mathcal{Z}$ is an abstract set, it does not have a particular point. So I choose $t \in \mathcal{Z}$. But if it was the ball of radius $1$, I would have choosen its center. I would then have shown that for any point $z$ in the ball, $|f(z)|$ would have been bounded by some constant, involving the diameter of the ball and the value of $f$ at its center. Here, $f(z)$ cannot be too far away from the value of $f$ at the particular point $t$ I choose before.

Comment: I think I get it. I think. Thanks

Comment: The condition stated in your question says: for two points, you can bound the difference of their images by their distance plus a constant. Moreover, as you are on a compact set, if you choose any point and think of it as the center of your space, you can say that every point is not too far from the center. Then, your relation says that every point has a value not too far from the value at the center.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108527/discussion-between-amj-and-didier).